# Quel est le français pour « SQL » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, informatique, noms-propres, abréviations

J'ai cherché en ligne et j'ai trouvé 
« [langage d'interrogation de données](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langage_de_requ%C3%AAte) »

Personellement, j'aurais plutôt pensé que ça devrais
être « langue de requête structurée » ou quelque chose
d'assez proche. Qu'en dites vous?

Et j'aimerais aussi savoir ce qu'on dit « sur le tas » (comme on dit) 
est-qu'on dit `LID` ou `SQL` (je veux dire dans les pays
francophones) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SQL](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_Query_Language) est un nom propre (prononcé [ɛskyɛl]). On ne le traduit donc pas.

Si on veut expliquer ce que c'est, on peut effectivement traduire le terme anglais dont c'est l'acronyme : langage de requêtes structurées. (En informatique, on parle toujours de *langage*, jamais de *langue* — une langue est une langue humaine.) J'utilise plutôt le pluriel pour *requêtes* puisque c'est un langage qui sert à exprimer des requêtes, pas un langage qui sert à l'activité de requête.

Le terme « langage d'interrogation de données » dans l'article de Wikipédia ne désigne pas SQL, mais un de ses multiples sous-langages (la partie qui sert à sélectionner des entrées dans une table, je crois, autrement dit ce qu'on met après `select`).

Note : je suis développeur mais je n'ai jamais travaillé près des bases de données.

Comment: @PapaPoule Non, je voulais bien écrire *langage*, le mot français. Il est en italiques parce que je parle du mot, pas du concept. Merci, j'ai corrigé.

Comment: Tout à fait, il en va de même pour tous les autres langages informatiques et ce quelque soit leur nature.

Comment: Je suis développeur, j'utilise régulièrement des bases de données, et je confirme :)

Comment: @Gilles dans les pays francophones, utilisez-vous "ess-cul-elle" ou "elle-i-dé" quand vous travaillez quotidiennement? p.s. merci de votre réponse - s'il n'y a rien de mieux dans les jours qui suivent, je la marquerai comme correcte!

Comment: @Vérace Je n'ai jamais entendu une autre prononciation que "ess-cul-elle" en France.

Comment: @Vérace > Travaillant en Belgique, donc entouré de collègues dont la langue maternelle n'est pas forcément le français, j'entends régulièrement  prononcé en un seul mot "sicouel" (désolé je ne sais pas écrire en phonétique), mais  de mémoire tous les francophones que j'ai cotoyés prononcaient effectivement chacune des lettres.

Answer (score 2):

SQL est avant tout un acronyme.

Il fait surtout l'objet d'une standardisation et normalisation : SQL:2011 ou ISO/CEI 9075:2011 . voir https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011 . Donc il est pris tel quel.

En France, les termes informatiques sont très souvent conservés sous leur forme d'origine (quasiment toujours en anglais). Je n'ai jamais vu l'usage de LID.

Certains sont quelquefois traduits pourtant: AGL (IDE). PGI (ERP), peut-être en raison d'une pression commerciale.

C'est vrai souvent aussi des termes technologiques et scientifiques selon leur percée historique (vieux termes en chimie, médecine, ...).

La décomposition de l'acronyme peut quelquefois être francisée: FAQ (foire aux questions, GSM qui a plusieurs décompositions).

la prononciation dépend: des liaisons phonétiques quand c'est possible: WIFI, ou l'énoncé des lettres avec des consonnes successives: SQL, GSM

Comment: Que veut dire GSM en français?

Comment: @Verace  GSM est maintenant Global System for Mobile,c'était à l'origine français:  Groupe Spécial Mobile. voir  https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_System_for_Mobile_Communications

Comment: Pour une fois qu'un terme français devient la norme anglaise! Je bossais dans la biologie et les gens utilisaient constamment des mots anglais quand il y avait des équivalents français convenables. Bien qu'anglophone, je luttais contre, mais sans beaucoup de succès!